# Unable to get closest element with certain class jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that catches whether the input has changed or not then if the value is exceeding the max it sets the value to the max. So you can not enter a value over the max. But if you try to do this I want to display an error message but I am struggling to get the closest error message. Here is my code;

```js
$(document).on('keydown keyup', '.quantity input', function(e) {
  var max = Number($(this).attr('max'));

  if ($(this).val() > max) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(max);
    $(this).closest('.quant_warn').show();
  } else if ($(this).val() < 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quantity">
  <label>Quantity: </label>

  <div class="increment">
    <span></span><span></span>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="1" min="1" max="10">

  <div class="decrement">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="quant_warn" style="display: none;">only 10 in stock</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should change your code from ` $(this).closest('.quant_warn').show();` to ` $(this).closest('.quantity').find('.quant_want').show();`  as the class `.quant_warn` is not wraped over the `input` which is the object `this` in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `.quant_warn` div isn't a parent of the `input` but a sibling, you need to use **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** instead :

```
$(this).siblings('.quant_warn').show();
```

**NOTE :** It will be more efficient to use `input` event instead of `keydown keyup` when you track the use inputs.

```js
$(document).on('input', '.quantity input', function(e) {
  var max = Number($(this).attr('max'));

  if ($(this).val() > max) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(max);
    $(this).siblings('.quant_warn').show();
  } else if ($(this).val() < 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quantity">
  <label>Quantity: </label>

  <div class="increment">
    <span></span><span></span>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="1" min="1" max="10">

  <div class="decrement">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="quant_warn" style="display: none;">only 10 in stock</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. I will try use input instead but I used Keydown Keyup as it doesn't conflict with the WooCommerce js for the inputs

Answer (score 3):

Try this for better solution

```js
$(document).on('keydown keyup', '.quantity input', function(e) {
    var max = Number($(this).attr('max'));
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (val) {
      if (val > max) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(max);
        $(this).siblings('.quant_warn').show();
      } else {
        $(this).siblings('.quant_warn').hide();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <label>Quantity: </label>

  <div class="increment">
    <span></span><span></span>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="1" min="1" max="10">

  <div class="decrement">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="quant_warn" style="display: none;">only 10 in stock</div>
</div>
```